# Why does my dataloader load empty batches?

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to fine-tune the MaskFormer model based on your tutorial. However, I am running into some problems with the dataloader. Sometimes the training continues for one iteration before showing the error. Sometimes it doesn't. But it doesn't train for more than one iteration. Here's the screenshot of the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPB8M.png)

The code below also behaves the similar way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u7rN.png)

Could someone please help me?

Here's the entire notebook if you want to take a look: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pE9wyx6RUmQbqyzGBpOWs-m_nCOPYQZ1?usp=sharing

I didn't expect any empty batches in the loader because I followed the notebook step-by-step. I tried reducing the batch size, num_workers = 0

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-d508975bf819> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 cnt = 0
      2 
----> 3 for item in train_dataloader:
      4   print(item)
      5   cnt += 1

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in stack(arrays, axis, out)
    420     arrays = [asanyarray(arr) for arr in arrays]
    421     if not arrays:
--> 422         raise ValueError('need at least one array to stack')
    423 
    424     shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}

ValueError: need at least one array to stack
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is because the code is using this random crop from albumentations, `A.RandomCrop(width=512, height=512),` - which means sometimes it's ending up with crops with no labels and crashes.

try replaceing that line with this instead     `A.CropNonEmptyMaskIfExists(width=512, height=512),`

https://albumentations.ai/docs/api_reference/augmentations/crops/transforms/#albumentations.augmentations.crops.transforms.CropNonEmptyMaskIfExists